# Do I need to declare my Apple Watch that I got as a gift in the US customs form?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I already have a smart watch and I got another one as gift for my friend. Do I need to declare both or just the one which is a gift?

Comment: Which border, what is your citizenship, where from and where to do you travel and what is the value of the watches (each.)

Comment: @willeke we know the border (US), I don’t think citizenship is relevant here, where from neither, and the value of the watch does not have an influence on the answer. The only thing that matters to fill the customs form is whether any goods were acquired or received abroad and will stay in the US.

Comment: @jcaron the value of the watches is relevant to the customs duty, however, as is residence, because the US exemption is higher for residents.

Comment: @phoog if I recall correctly, the US customs form asks for the total value of the goods, not whether they are they are above or below the exemption, am I wrong?

Comment: @jcaron that is correct.  The traveler is supposed to declare the goods even if their value does not exceed the exemption.  The effect of the declaration is the only thing that depends on the factors I mentioned.  Your original statement about importation of goods is correct; I just wanted to point out that there are additional considerations that are not mentioned in the question but of interest to travelers, especially to those who might not realize that declaring goods doesn't necessarily mean paying duty.